# Facebook SDK Import

Tags: android, facebook, import, sdk

i am trying to import Facebook SDK. I did steps in facebook developers page. But after the import , when i try clean project it gives that error to me.

```
 C:\Users\bahadır\workspace\Shahahaps1\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\com_facebook_button_icon.png: error: Duplicate file.
 C:\Users\bahadır\workspace\Shahahaps1\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_button_icon.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bahadır\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I looked everypage about that but i can't find any appropriate thing , how can i solve this ?

Comment: How do you import the SDK?

Comment: File - New - Import Module - Path of facebook directory. Then i add repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

Comment: Do you have the latest version of SDK on your hard drive? And would probably be easier to import it as a Gradle dependency.

Comment: Yes my SDK is latest. i add                                                                       --compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile project(':facebook')-- to dependencies

Comment: It's enough to add just the Gradle dependency, you don't need to import the module. This may be the cause of the problem since you're importing the same library twice.

Comment: Well if it says, that the file is duplicate you should maybe delete the non original? Of course it would be wise to backup the files before. Would be my first guess..

Comment: without import it gives this error :     Error:(26, 0) Project with path ':facebook' could not be found in project ':app'.
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>

Comment: I did Sebastian , but whenever i clean or build project it automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in your gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' repositories { mavenCentral() }
```

and

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

and then produce your hash key in your main activity.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "theo.testing.facebookapp",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for(Signature signature:info.signatures){
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("KeyHash : " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and if you run your basic app,you will get back a hash key having 28 characters. ie something like c5DLQUsd4SWWP4aoZ7jKV9ojYd5=

I uploaded in github a [project](https://github.com/theo82/FacebookApp/tree/1.01_setting_up) using facebook sdk.